# ruby Screen Scraping Library for formatting times

Tags: ruby, web-scraping

I am wondering if there is a library method out there that will take a time string of unknown format and reformat it into a standard format (i.e. HHMM).  Examples of the type of thing I am getting from websites are.

1030 10:30 10pm 10PM 1030PM 10pm
1030PM 1030p.m. 1030pm. 930 930am 
9am 8.30 8.30pm

and I am sure there are others.

I started to write a method and it's getting there (https://gist.github.com/funkytwig/b47551e98e8698ebb59310286982a6ce) but wondering if there is already one around. It is worth mentioning I have come across websites where the times in the same list (i.e. event listing) are not consistent, I think they are hand typed into a text field when input.

Just to clarify I am wondering if there is a method in a library already existing, i'm not asking people to debug my code. I'm just sharing it to show what I have done to try to solve the problem, and you will see why I am hoping there is a library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic#examples). It can parse a whole lot of time formats, including the ones that you gave.